# what's wrong with this function (the testFunction)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .button_test{
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color:#999; 
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="button_test">debug</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var testFunction = function(_callback){
            $(".button_test").click(function(){
                if ("function"==typeof(_callback)) {
                    _callback();
                };
            })
        }
        testFunction(function(){
            console.log(111);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The function testFunction has been used only once, so I think when I clcik `$(".button_test")` at the first time, the console will output 111. Then no matter how many times I click `$(".button_test")` ,the console would output nothing.
However, in fact, everytime `$(".button_test")` being clicked, the console would output 111.

Comment: I see no error, I can see 111 in console

Comment: `Then no matter how many times I click $(".button_test") ,the console would no output.
However, in fact, everytime $(".button_test") being clicked, the console would output 111.` What is happening? You get each time 111 or only the first time?

Comment: HUH? So you are saying that it only outputs once or does it output multiple times and you only expect it once?

Comment: Than that is not how you would code it to output once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click does not run an event once, it runs every single time the event occurs. Only way to stop it would be to unbind the event or add a flag inside to say not run. BUT there is a better way because jQuery has a method in to run an event once, that would be [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> **one()**
>
> `.one( events [, data ], handler(eventObject) )` Returns: `jQuery`
>
> **Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

And your code can use it like this

```
    var testFunction = function(_callback){
        $(".button_test").one("click", function(){
            if ("function"==typeof(_callback)) {
                _callback();
            };
        })
    }
    testFunction(function(){
        console.log(111);
    });
```

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason for him wanting to code the event handler this way (inside a function), please explain why that's not required or he'll continue what may simply be a bad practice due to misunderstanding.  Help him a little more than just fix his code.

Comment: @Archer I have no idea why the OP write it that way and that is a common pattern.

Comment: I only mention it because whenever I've seen someone do something similar, it's turned out that they were following an example they'd seen somewhere and didn't realise that it was a convoluted way of doing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

You are registering a `click` event handler on `.button_test`. Unless you [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the event, it will be launched each time you clic on the element.

The behavior you describe is the expected behavior.

See the doc for [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and/or [bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not `testfunction` that's attached to `.button_test` as the click handler, but that anonymous function that executes `console.log(111)`.

Nothing changes the click handler on `.button_test` after that one time you run `testfunction`, so the button continues to execute `console.log(111)` every time.